# How do i show places, in google maps api v3 and google places api, between two points?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

How to show places nearby certain radius starting from every point of a route path between two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

- The Places API will return at most 60 results in groups of 20.
- There is an infinite number of points along a route.

You can investigate the [RouteBoxer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/), but to do what you want you will need a source of data besides the Places API.

Comment: Do you know are there any ports of RouteBoxer to other languages other than javascript, e.g. Swift?